# ASP.Net MVC, View @class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, view

I want to put a font awesome beside my link in a side nav bar, i have added this to the _layout view:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Bookings", "Index", "Booking", new { @class = "fa fa-table" })</li>
```

It renders fine but the navigation gets messed up and and crashes:

```
http://localhost:54155/Length=6
```

why is it giving me lenght=6 ?

I see i am only accessing to the class, but im sure i nedd to include the  tag somewhere, but dont know how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overload you are using is incorrect - you need to use

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Mechanic Ranking", "Rankings", "Report", null, new { @class = "fa fa-area-chart" })</li>
```

MSDN Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx).

The reason you are seeing length=6 is that the class is being interpreted as a route value rather than an HTML attribute, due to it being passed in the position of the routevalues parameter rather than the htmlattributes parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Rankings", "Report")"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i> Mechanic Ranking</a>
```